# MYSQL - Select only if row in LEFT JOIN is not present

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 2 simple mysql tables. The first 1 called mail and has 2 rows:

```
sender | receiver
Marley | Bob 
Saget  | Bob
```

The second one called block and has 1 row:

```
blocker | blocked
  Bob   | Marley
```

I want to select sender(s) from the first table who sent Bob emails but aren't blocked in the block table. So the results should be:

```
sender 
 saget
```

I tried the following query but it's not returning results:

```
SELECT * FROM mail  
LEFT JOIN block ON (block.blocker = 'Bob') 
WHERE (block.blocked <> mail.sender)
```

Comment: But `Saget` is blocked by `Bob`

Comment: Actually the result shouldn't be `saget`, because you see, Bob already blocked both of them.

Comment: sorry i made a stupid mistake...marley is only blocked while saget not

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The left join will produce `null` rows for the mismatches.
It's those `null` rows that you need to filter on.

```
SELECT * FROM mail  
LEFT JOIN block ON (block.blocker = 'Bob') 
WHERE block.blocker IS NULL
```

It's kind of strangle to be joining on a fixed value however, a more common join (given your tables) would be:

```
SELECT * FROM mail  
LEFT JOIN block ON (block.blocker = mail.receiver
                and block.blocked = mail.sender)<<-- these should match
WHERE block.blocker IS NULL                     <<-- select only mismatches
AND mail.receiver like 'bob';
```

Comment: You are joining with the hardcoded value for `'Bob'`?, and nothing else?. That doesn't seems right

Comment: So, now you are done?. I think that this is still missing a condition, you should also check that the sender is being blocked

Comment: I think the second line in your second solution should be like this: `LEFT JOIN block ON (block.blocker = mail.receiver AND block.blocker = 'Bob')`??

Comment: Thanks Johan :) I'm now trying a different query that's causing also another problem with a very similar scenario so will post it in a new question

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
SELECT sender
FROM mail m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM block 
                  WHERE blocker = m.receiver 
                  AND blocked = m.sender)
```

Comment: Probably should add a `AND Receiver = 'Bob'` since he specifies he wants to look for messages from Bob.

Comment: @JNK Yes, I thought about that requirement, but was hesitant to add that condition, since the `block` table is (apparently) supposed to have all blockers, not only `Bob`

Comment: Thanks Lamak :) I'm now trying a different query that's causing also another problem with a very similar scenario so will post it in a new question